# Place Your Bets 2 - In sequence, of course

Tags: logical-deduction, number-sequence, probability

> ### Your Cards...
>
> [image: Your Cards]

You have to figure out what the next row of 4 cards will be.

There is a pattern in there somewhere, promise.

*Good Luck*

Comment: I will give a small hint, ACES are low only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Answer is:

> 9-Spades | Jack-Hearts | Ace-Spades | 5-Clubs
>  They are adding four upwards (rotating to Ace after King)
>  the suit appears to be that of the card above and left

Although I'm not 100% on the suit for the first one. If the top right card was 10 Hearts I'd be absolutely certain, so perhaps there's something else going on here than what first appears.

Card one:

> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9

Card two:

> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> Jack

Card three:

> 10 -> Jack -> Queen -> King -> Ace

Card Four:

> Ace -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5

After not being 100% happy with the answer above, I have come up with an alternate answer that would make sense of the suit thing:

> 9-Diamonds | Jack-Hearts | Ace-Hearts | 5-Clubs

If that is the correct answer I'll explain how I got that instead.

Comment: Great work, @Smock! I really thought this one would last a minute. Ok, back to the drawing board. They are going to get progressively harder, lol.